# Determine rationality under limitations

Tags: elements

Now I know $x$ is irrational and $\left(x+1\right)\left(x+3\right)$ is rational.

I want to determine which of the following four expressions is rational:

A. $x^2$

B. $\left(x+2\right)^2$

C. $\left(x-2\right)^2$

D. $\left(x-1\right)\left(x-3\right)^2$

The answer is B, but I'm wondering if there is a workable way - without manual analysis - to determine this?

I made attempt:

```
y = (x + 1) (x + 3);
While[Element[x, Reals] == True && Element[x, Rationals] == False && 
  Element[y, Rationals] == True; Element[x^2, Rationals]]
```

(Just learned Mathematica, so apologies for my stupid languages)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the definition of rational that you're using if $x^2$ is not considered rational? Could you provide the definition or a manual analysis showing why $x^2$ isn't rational just so we can be sure everyone's on the same page looking at this question?

Comment: @eyorble $\left(x+1\right)\left(x+3\right)=x^2+4x+3$. $4x+3$, apparently, is irrational (because integer times of a irrational number[except 0] is always irrational), so $x^2$'s irrational.

Comment: @eyorble Sorry that there was a typo in my question. It should be "x is rational" instead of x^2.

Answer (score 1):

***Note.** In [version 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/272282/1) of this question, it was assumed that $x^2$ is irrational. In [version 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/272282/2) it is assumed that $x$ is irrational. But note that these assumptions are equivalent, given the second assumption that $(x+1)(x+3) = x^2 + 4x + 3$ is rational, which is the same in versions 1 and 2. This is an answer to version 1 of the question, but, as just explained, is also a valid answer for version 2. I prefer to leave it in this form, since I find it slightly easier to explain what is going on. Perhaps OP will consider changing the question back to version 1?*

I use the symbol $i$ for the irrational number $x^2$, and $r$ for the rational number $(x+1)(x+3)$. Warning: $i$ is not $\sqrt{-1}$ in this answer.

Every polynomial in $x$ is equal to a sum of

- a polynomial in $r$
- $i$ times a polynomial in $r$

all with rational coefficients. The function `rewrite` computes this.

**Code.** We use a [Groebner basis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html):

```
(* Groebner basis using the default lexicographic order
   with x before i before r in the list of variables *)
gb = GroebnerBasis[{x^2-i,(x+1)*(x+3)-r},{x,i,r}];
rewrite[poly_] := Collect[Last[PolynomialReduce[poly,gb,{x,i,r}]],i];
```

**Example.** To decide if $2x^3+7x^2$ is rational or irrational, use

```
rewrite[2*x^3+7*x^2]
(* 9/2+i (1/2-r/2)-3 r+r^2/2 *)
```

We are interested in the coefficient of $i$, which is $\frac12-\frac12 r$. If it is zero, then $2x^3+7x^2$ is rational. If this is nonzero, then $2x^3+7x^2$ is irrational.

But $\frac12-\frac12 r=0$ if and only if $r=1$. We conclude:

- If $r=1$ then $2x^3+7x^2$ is rational.
- If $r \neq 1$ then $2x^3+7x^2$ is irrational.

The first case, $r=1$, is in some sense exceptional but does occur, namely for $x = -2 \pm \sqrt{2}$. One can also see that $x^2$ is irrational for these two $x$.

Comment: Sorry that there was a typo in my question. It should be "x is rational" instead of x^2. I get your meaning, something, however, should be fixed because of my stupid typo?

Comment: Please see the new note at the beginning. To make the assumption that $x$ is irrational, one can replace `x^2-i` by `x-i` in the Groebner basis. Then of course $x=i$ so introducing $i$ becomes superfluous, you could also simply forget about `i` at that point and use `gb=GroebnerBasis[{(x+1)*(x+3)-r},{x,r}]; rewrite[poly_]:=Collect[Last[PolynomialReduce[poly,gb,{x,r}]],x];`.